# how to convert org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame with single row and single column into an integer value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

consider querying hive data from inside spark using

```
val selectMemCntQry = "select column1 from table1 where column2 = "+col_2_val
    val table_col2 = sparkSession.sql(selectMemCntQry)
    val diff = table_col2 - file_member_count
```

where file_member_count is an integer value.I know result of table_col2 is always going to a single number
I want to subtract result of the query from an integer value.But error that I am facing is 
value - is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val Row(colum1: Integer) = sparkSession.sql(selectMemCntQry).first
colum1 - file_member_count
```

or

```
sparkSession.sql(selectMemCntQry).first.getAs[Integer]("column1") - file_member_count
```

or

```
sparkSession.sql(selectMemCntQry).as[Integer].first - file_member_count
```